# Do setUp and tearDown methods run for each method or at the beginning and at the end of TestCase

Tags: python, python-unittest

### Do test methods which are members of the same TestCase affect each other ?

In python unittest I try to understand that if i change a variable in a test method, does the variable change in other test method . Or do setUp and tearDown methods run for each method and so variables set up again for each method ?

I mean

```
AsdfTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.dict = {
                     'str': 'asdf',
                     'int': 10
                    }
    def tearDown(self):
        del self.dict

    def test_asdf_1(self):
        self.dict['str'] = 'test string'

    def test_asdf_2(self):
        print(self.dict)
```

So I am asking which output **test_asdf_2()** will print 
**'asdf'** or **'test_string'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, setUp and tearDown run before EACH test (i.e. function starting with 'test' in the name) in the testcase class. Consider this example:

```
# in file testmodule
import unittest

class AsdfTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self)      : print('setUp called')
    def tearDown(self)   : print('tearDown called')
    def test_asdf_1(self): print( 'test1 called' )
    def test_asdf_2(self): print( 'test2 called' )
```

Calling it from the command line:

```
 $ python3 -m unittest -v testmodule
test_asdf_1 (testmodule.AsdfTestCase) ... setUp called
test1 called
tearDown called
ok
test_asdf_2 (testmodule.AsdfTestCase) ... setUp called
test2 called
tearDown called
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

---

(therefore, yes, in your example, it would pring 'asdf' since the setUp is re-executed, overwriting the changes caused by test 2)

Comment: Thank you, using print in setUp and tearDown methods is simple and very clear way to understand. Should have come to mind

Answer (score 2):

Each Test Case is real in isolation. The setup method is ran before each Test Case and the teardown is ran after each Test Case.

So to answer your question, if you change a variable in your Test Case it will not affect other Test Cases.

You were on the right path by writing test code. It's always a better learning experience when you do it yourself. However, here's your answer.

Example code:

```
import unittest

class AsdfTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    print "Set Up"
    self.dict = {
      'str': 'asdf',
      'int': 10
    }

  def tearDown(self):
    print "Tear Down"
    self.dict = {}

  def test_asdf_1(self):
    print "Test 1"
    self.dict['str'] = 'test string'
    print self.dict

  def test_asdf_2(self):
    print "Test 2"
    print self.dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
Set Up
Test 1
{'str': 'test string'}
Tear Down
.Set Up
Test 2
{}
Tear Down
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

You can see that the set up method is run before each test. Then the tear down method is run after each test.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I edited my question for explain myself better. I'll glad if you look at again